# Autolayout UIButtons in a grid

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm having trouble getting my `UIButtons` to align properly in my scrollview. I have tried aligned baselines, aligning each to a my `UIView` called contentView, etc. and nothing has worked.

Essentially I have a:

```
`UIView`

   `UIScrollView`   //320 x 708

      `UIVew`   //320 x 708 , called contentView
```

I have 8 `UIButtons` sizes 140x140, that are aligned two to a row as such:

```
|---8 pts--| UIButton |---24 pts--|  UIButton |---8 pts--|
               _
               |
               |
              8 pts
               _

|---8 pts--| UIButton |---24 pts--|  UIButton |---8 pts--|
```

etc, for 4 rows

Comment: What are the results?

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq I can't describe it, its a bunch of misized squares that are both too big and too small.

Comment: Fixed width + fixed height of 140px for all 8 buttons + spacings of 8px should do it, but unlike width & height constraints that you can set up all at once, do not try to set spacing constraints to multiple buttons at once. As you only have 8 of them, proceed one by one. Ex: the first button is top and left-spaced of 8px to its superview. The second button is also top-spaced of 8px to its superview, but right-spaced of 8px to its superview, etc. Also note that you might have conflicts with sizes with this layout: 8+140+8+140+8 = 304px, different from the 320px width of the superview...

Comment: @Romain, sorry, meant 24 pts between each grid. If I laid this out programmatically could I avoid autolayout? Trying your suggestions now

Comment: @Romain your answer worked !

Comment: Glad you worked it out! I've posted it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my suggestions as an answer, as it seems to solve the problem:

Equal widths + equal heights + spacings of 8px (or 24px) should do it, but unlike fixed widths & heights constraints that you can set up all at once, do not try to set equal size or spacing constraints to multiple buttons at once. As you only have 8 of them, proceed one by one.

Ex: the first button is top and left-spaced of 8px to its superview. The second button is also top-spaced of 8px to its superview, but right-spaced of 8px to its superview, and left-spaced of 24px to the first button. The first and second buttons should also have equal widths constraints set up. Etc for all rows.

Also note that in your first version of the question, you could have conflicts with sizes: 8+140+8+140+8 = 304px, different from the 320px width of the superview... If you try to wire up everything with constraints, you *will* get conflicts, so the key is to wire up just enough constraints for the view to appear correctly, but not too much to avoid generating conflicts which are sometimes hard to resolve...

Comment: one edit you need to add is adding EQUAL WIDTHS to each row (only buttons in the same row).

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was moving from aspect ratio on all buttons to equal width and heights ! Then setting 3 constraints on the left buttons (top, left and bottom) and 4 on the right (top, left, bottom and right)